# Play next file automatically using MediaPlayer Control(AxWindowsMediaPlayer)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-media-player, axwindowsmediaplayer

When changing AxWindowsMediaPlayer URL in PlayStateChange Event, it doesn't start playing automatically, just changes to "Ready" state.

I have an "AxWindowsMediaPlayer" Control in my C# WinForms program. when I normally change the `URL` property of WindowsMediaPlayer1, it works fine and plays new mp3 file automatically.

When the song ended WindowsMediaPlayer1 State changes to `Stopped` and I Want next `URL` automatically start Playing.

I used `PlayStatChange` event, so when player state is `Stopped`, `URL` Will change, but Not playing automatically!

The player goes to `Ready` State until I press the play button on the WindowsMediaPlayer1.

Here is the Code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "6.mp3"; //Works fine      
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "4.mp3"; //Works fine. It changes the music.
}
private void WindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange(object sender, 
    AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e)
{
    if (e.newState == 1) //1 is for "Stopped" State
        WindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "5.mp3"; 
    // Here is the problem. 
    // URL Will change but player goes to "Ready" State 
    // But not in "playing" until I press the play button in control.
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in media player [documentations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmp/axwmplib-axwindowsmediaplayer-url--vb-and-c?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#remarks), you should not set the `Url` from event handler code. Instead you can play next file this way:

```
private void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange(object sender, 
    AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e)
{
    if (e.newState == 1) 
    {
        this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
            this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = @"address of nextfile";
        }));
    }   
}
```

Also as another option you can consider using a [playlist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmp/playlists-and-media-items?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235).

Answer (score 0):

I found this note on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562470(v=vs.85).aspx) about player.URL:

"Do not call this method from event handler code. Calling URL from an event handler may yield unexpected results."

so I tried another way to solve it and its worked.

added a timer and a bool varible to check if WindowsMediaPlayer1 is "Stopped"

Here is the solution:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool nextURL = false;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "5.mp3";                   
    }

    private void WindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e)
    {
        if (e.newState == 1) // 1 is consider for  "Stopped" State
        {
            nextURL = true;   // if the song ended "nextURL" flag sets to true
        }   
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (nextURL)
        {
            WindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "6.mp3";
            nextURL = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to use a timer, you can simply use this.BeginInvoke to set the url. it's the same as changing url after that event.